# "Messing up" a setting/tuning?

Tags: verbs

Say somebody turns (or *plays, fiddles with*) the knobs of an old, analog radio with a tuning dial set to a station, resulting in loss of reception - what would that be called, analogous to negatively connotated verbs such as *misalign*, *break*? Maybe *misadjust*? *Unset*?

---

Sorry, I was too specific about the scenario, giving the old radio as example in the question body. Is there a more general term for "messing up" a setting? *Unprogram* a VCR? *Misconfigure* the microwave? It's not really *breaking* something. What about an alarm clock? 
Maybe there isn't just one general verb for this?

Comment: From what I can faintly recall, '... lost the station' was most common.

Comment: Depends very much on the context and intended audience.

Comment: Informally in BrE you'd probably just exclaim "you've *buggered* it" - which broadly means to have put something into a disordered or broken state. I can't think of a formal term that is generic to all forms of upsetting. A microwave may simply be "set wrong", an alarm clock might be "changed" (with an ominous tone to reinforce the undesirability of the change), whereas the tuning of broadcast stations like Edwin says may be "lost".

Answer (score 2):

Since you *tune into* a station, how about *detune*? So you could say someone fiddled with the dial, detuning the radio and causing loss of reception.

definition of *tune in*: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tune-in -
`to watch or listen to a particular television or radio programme or station`

definition of *detune*: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detune - `to put (a radio receiver) out of tune or resonance (as by varying capacity or inductance)`

Comment: That looks about right. To round out your answer, add a link to a definition and quote the definition, then do the same for an example of the word *detune* used that way.

Comment: To an electronics nerd, "detune" suggests messing with the IF transformers inside the radio.

Comment: @HotLicks I'll never forget the guy who brought me his boombox to be fixed coz he couldn't tune _anything_. I noticed some missing fasteners, and asked him if he had messed with  the unit. He said 'yes', but just to screw down the "loose screws in the little plastic thingies" he found on the PC board in the tuning section...